# how to remember the return-to page when visiting a detailpage from different parent pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have a page which lists a collection of objects and a detail page for the object details.
There is a link for every row in the list to the details page.

At the bottom of the details page, i have a hardcoded [Go back] link, which will send you to the list page you just came from.

So far so good.

But now i also want to link to the details page from a, new, dashboard page.

What is a smart way to remember the list page when clicking on the list to go to the details page so i can return to the right list page?

I thought about the session, or maybe i can read the 'from' page in a controller-action-parameters format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the *go-back* link as query string parameter to the details action in addition to the id of the object you are going to show the details about.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id, string returnUrl)
{
    ...
}
```

The returnUrl parameter could then be used in the corresponding view to generate the *Go-Back* link.

Comment: Sorry i didn't include this one in my question already. I've read this solution (probably by you :-)) somewhere else, but as a matter of personal taste i don't realy like the view of url's being used for 'remembering' data. This is not an architectual taste, it's more that when i see data like 'prevpage=1' of 'returnpage=\data\goodies' it's pure the view of it which i don't like (i wish i could better describe it, but my English isn't that good)

Comment: Other solutions include saving the ReturnUrl in the Session. Personally I never use the Session and never recommend it to people, that's why I didn't mention it in my answer but if you prefer using Sessions feel free.

Comment: Allright, that's fair. Do TempData and ViewData also us Session in the background?

Comment: TempData, yes, ViewData, no. But don't use TempData because TempData lasts only for a single request which I don't think is the behavior you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

public ActionResult Details(int id, string returnUrl)
    {
        ...
    }

Set a hidden value with tag name as "returnurl" in the view. When  the user clicks on button, it navigates to this page, you can find the value in returnurl.

Depending upon the value in returnurl, you can navigate to the required page.

Regards,
Pavan.G